# Basic HTML Internal Link not working in IE8

Tags: html, internal-link

This one has me scratching my head. I have a page with several internal links bringing the user down the page to further content. Beneath various sections there are further internal links bringing the user back to the top. This works fine in all browsers apart from IE8 (actual IE8 - not IE9 in IE8 mode) where they work go down, but not coming back up!

Examples:

```
<a href="page.php?v=35&amp;u=admin-videos#a">A &ndash; General</a>
.... //travelling DOWN the page
<h3><strong>A &ndash; General<a name="a"></a></strong></h3>

<a name="top"></a>
.... //travelling back up
<a href="page.php?v=35&amp;u=admin-videos#top">Back to top.</a>
```

I've tried filling the 'top' anchor with `&nbsp;` but that hasn't changed it. Any ideas?

Actual use case: http://databizsolutions.ie/contents/page.php?v=35&u=admin-videos

Answer (score 1):

Try to give it like

```
<a href="#top">Back to top.</a>
```

put it like this, I hope it will work

```
   <a name="top">Title Text here</a>  
    <a href="#top">go to top</a>
```

Comment: Tried it, but it needs the query string to stay on the page.

Comment: Do not give whole page path as you do not need to go to server you just want to jump to top of page (just scroll up)

Comment: leaving out the path results in a link pointing to http://databizsolutions.ie/contents#top which kicks me back to the index page. I've edited the usecase to display this

Comment: There is an editable example over here http://www.ezineasp.net/Samples/HTML/HTML-Basics/HTML-Hyperlink-Bookmark-Tag/Default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Using `<a name="...">` is as old as last millenium. Use an `id` attribute on an existing element. Preferably the exact one you are targeting. Then you can do cool stuff with the `:target` CSS selector.
2. Do not include the full filename when you just want to change the hash. Just `<a href="#top">` works perfectly fine.

Comment: :target is not supported in lteIE8 I believe?

Comment: Hmm... I honestly can't remember. Still, for *newer* browsers you can do cool stuff :p

Comment: Yes. Yes you can. :)

I checked, and it's not supported for letIE8, and 'buggy' on Safari 1.3 and 2.0. Oh well. http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-target#compatibilitysection

Comment: Back to the point, though, did the answer solve the problem any?

Comment: Well, seeing as I have to stick with `<a name...` then I'm still stuck. Adil and yourself are saying I dont need the full path (which I originally thought also), but they won't work without it. And they DO work when going down the page, just not when going up - I'm baffled!